# how to choose more than one category using ifelse

Tags: r

I have been trying to subset the five categories of a column variable genhlth into "good health" or "poor health". So far, I have tried this code. 
What is best way of classifying these 5 categories into 2?

```
brfss2013_subset2$goodhealth = ifelse(brfss2013_subset2$genhlth =="Excellent",
                                        "Very good", "Good", 1, 
                                    ifelse(is.na(brfss2013_subset2$genhlth), NA, 0))
```

Comment: Your code is confusing.  What is the expected output,  Is it 1, 0 or 'Very good", "Good"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an ifelse statement with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55944124/how-to-make-an-ifelse-statement-with-multiple-conditions)

Answer (score 1):

The `%in%` operator allows you to check against a vector of possible values.

```r
brfss2013_subset2$goodhealth = ifelse(brfss2013_subset2$genhlth %in% c("Excellent", "Very good", "Good"), 1, 0)
```

You don’t need to check for `NA` because `ifelse()` will automatically return `NA` if the input is `NA`.

You could also take advantage of the fact that `TRUE` has a numerical representation of 1 and `FALSE` of 0 and write:

```r
brfss2013_subset2$goodhealth = as.numeric(brfss2013_subset2$genhlth %in% c("Excellent", "Very good", "Good"))
```