# How to make an ifelse statement with multiple conditions

Tags: r

I am trying to create a dummy variable that tells me whether it the outcome was a win or a loss with values 1 and 0.

I tried using an ifelse statement on one line using c() to put all of the matching words in it. It gives me an error message and doesn't classify all of the tuples correctly.

```
game$homewin<- ifelse(game$outcome == c("home win OT",
                      "home win REG", "home win SO"), 1, 0)
```

I want it to give me a 1 in the game$homewin column when the home team wins and a 0 when the home team loses. All of the outcomes fall under 6 categories "home win OT", "home win REG", "home win SO", "away win OT", "away win REG" and "away win SO". I just want to be able to make a homewin column that does not discriminate of what type of win it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%in%` operator allows you to check against a vector of possible values.

```r
game$homewin <- ifelse(game$outcome %in% c("home win OT",
                    "home win REG", "home win SO"), 1, 0)
```

You could also take advantage of the fact that `TRUE` has a numerical representation of 1 and `FALSE` of 0 and write:

```r
game$homewin <- as.numeric(game$outcome %in% c("home win OT",
                    "home win REG", "home win SO"))
```

Comment: Almost exactly my answer [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55927387/1422451)! Only I used `as.integer`.

Comment: @Parfait I had another one [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55891499/how-to-choose-more-than-one-category-using-ifelse/55891555#55891555) too!